# Google Cloud HTTP 503 Errors blocking all requests in google cloud run periodically

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

Every few hours, my google cloud run application will timeout all HTTP requests and give the error message:

"Google Cloud HTTP 503 Error: Intermittent Request Failures with Malformed HTTP Response or Connection Errors."

We are a Node.Js application.

I have troubleshooted on the link they provide. Our containers are set to auto scale, and the CPU usage gradually increases until the container crashes. This seems to stop when I rebuild the application, suggesting that it is something that builds up over time.

I also started logging the file descriptors, and noticed that we're increasing these over time despite successfully cleaning them up.

I am really lost on how to proceed. The periodic nature of this does not scale with usage (these often happen in the middle of the night).

Comment: If the file descriptors increase, you have a leak somewhere. And it's hard to find it!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.